# Ad an empty span as first child of an element

Tags: javascript, dom, expression

When the script below executes, its supposed to insert an empty span element as the first child inside a "my_list li" list item...

```
*+html .my_list li{
    *zoom:expression(this.runtimeStyle.zoom=\"1\",
    this.insertBefore(document.createElement(\"span\") ).className=\"span\")
}
```

However, when I check the output in Internet Explorer, it still appears as if the element were appended to the end of the element.

Here's the content before the expression:

```
<li>Some element</li>
```

Here's what I want to achieve after the expression executes:

```
<li><span class="span"></span>Some element</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with jQuery 
jQuery
$("span").addClass("span");

Comment: I can do it either way, but 2 probs with your answer (1) span does not exist in dom yet. (2) Only want spans inserted for IE7 and below.

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span").addClass("span");
});
</script>
<![endif]-->